# Matrix elements in second quantisation formalism

Tags: hamiltonian, many-body, second-quantization, matrix-elements

In a system with two orbitals $c$ and $d$ (each with two spin degrees of freedom), consider the Hamiltonian $$H=V(d^{\dagger}_{\uparrow} c_{\uparrow} + c^{\dagger}_{\uparrow}d_{\uparrow}+d^{\dagger}_{\downarrow} c_{\downarrow} + c^{\dagger}_{\downarrow}d_{\downarrow}).$$ Also suppose that the many body states are indexed as $|n_{d_{\uparrow}}, n_{d_{\downarrow}}, n_{c_{\uparrow}} , n_{c_{\downarrow}}\rangle$ where $n$ shows the electron occupation number of each spin-orbital.

As mentioned in the literature, $\langle 1001|H|1100\rangle=V$ and $\langle0110|H|1100\rangle=-V$. However, according to my calculations, $H|1100\rangle=V(|0110\rangle+|1001\rangle)$ which gives $V$ for both matrix elements $\langle1001|H|1100\rangle$ and $\langle0110|H|1100\rangle$. I would like to know where my calculation goes wrong! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to link in the literature so that we may know if your initial Hamiltonian is defined correctly or not.

Comment: Of course. In the following virtual lecture on youtube at the minute 52 (the blue text):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4qEa8BWJCI&list=PLotxEOxVaaoKRXdDN-7lI3Y88PaHqyOZL&index=22&ab_channel=DrAndrewMitchell%27sphysicschannel

The Hamiltonian is written in the subspace ##Q=2, S_z=0##and I am only interested in the difference between the arrays ##H_{1,3}## and ##H_{2,3}## so I neglected the other terms of the Hamiltonian in my main post.

Comment: The problem may be in the sign in the definition of the states $|s_1s_2s_3s_4\rangle$. You could add the definitions in the question, then the only remaining work will be to apply commutation relations carefully.

Comment: As far as I know, the action of creation and annihilation operators on a many-body state does't make minus sign.  By which difinition we may obtain minus sign in the action of Hamiltonian on the state |1100>? I don't know how the minus sign may appear?